# GIt diff two hashes, show repo file size difference

Tags: git

If new people are using git sometimes they add files, and delete files  on their branch, not realizing the deleted files stay in the history.

How does one protect the deleted files from going into the main / dev branch, and increasing the repo size.

I realize squashing the commits would do this, but is there a way to git diff and show deleted / undeleted files on their branch to detect this?

Comment: What are you trying to avoid? What's the problem you're facing by asking about this solution?

Comment: new users to my repo sometimes add log files / temp files in a commit, and then several commits later they delete those.

When i review a merge request i only see the delta between main.  not the files that were added / deleted in their feature branch.  Trying to avoid log files in repo, when doing merge reviews wont show them.

Comment: Well.... I guess that's not a problem. After all, if a revision was created with that added file.... and some revisions later it was removed, well, what can git do? It's what the history was meant on those revisions.

Comment: IF a log file is very large it increases the repo size. I want a way to catch that during the merge review, and have the developer rewrite their feature branch history without the large files committed by mistake.

Comment: Right.... but so what? Why would you want to see a file that was added/deleted in the interim if it's not really a part of the final state of the branch? Don't get me wrong, I know that it has some value _if you are checking every revision_ of the MR. You might just as well ask to squash the branch before being submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to *take* each new commit from someone who offers you 50 commits (or any other number than 1), you must *inspect* each new commit.  There is no [Royal Road](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/royal+road+to) to this: it requires inspecting each commit.

If you intend to use `git merge --squash` or similar to convert all 50 of their commits into a single, new, different commit that just produces the same *end result*, then you can review the changes as a single change that produces the same end result, since that's what you will add to your repository.

That's really all there is to this.  Pick what you are going to do, and review accordingly.

Comment: Trying to balance recording how the work was done, not polluting the repo, and minimizing code reviews. 

I settled on creating a script in python that identifies commits in on their feature branch, and then steps through those commits looking for orphaned files.  

Debating if i want to go the extra mile and compare the size added from all commits, and size added from delta from dev.